# IDA map one memory address to another

Tags: ida, memory, address

I am trying to reverse engineer firmware for an embedded device. The memory region 0xA0000000-0xA1FFFFFF is mapped to 0x80000000-0x81FFFFF. How do I setup ida to recognise this?

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?